# Need help designing a regex or pyparsing approach to modify all words enclosed within pipes

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

For example:

```
blahblah|0A 4D 5E 43|adfsdasd|92| sgagrewas|12 5E|
```

Must become

```
blahblahx0Ax4Dx5Ex43adfsdasdx92 sgagrewasx12x5E
```

I'm trying something along the lines of: `re.sub(r'\|(\w+ ?)*\|', r'x\1', a)` But I'm having trouble getting it to work on more than the first match.

**UPDATE**: It looks like regex is not a good choice for this. Would a pyparsing solution be doable?

If not, I can write a simple iterative solution, but I would prefer something more extensible. But I'm having trouble getting it to work on more than the first match.

**UPDATE2**: I used a pure python approach in the end, it works fine and can deal with escape characters too.

```
def strtohex(self, string):
    hexmode = False
    hexstring = ''
    i=0
    while i<len(string):
        if string[i] == '\\':
            i += 1
            #No escape charecters inside hex pipes
            hexstring += string[i]   
        elif string[i] == '|':
            hexmode = not hexmode
        elif string[i] == ' ':
            hexstring += '' if hexmode else  ' '
        else:
            if hexmode:
                hexstring += chr(int(string[i:i+2],16))
                i += 1
            else:
                hexstring += string[i]

        i += 1
    return hexstring
```

Comment: Are the pieces of text and the hex numbers always alternating? Maybe an approach without regex would do.

Comment: No, the hex pieces can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: How can you, the human operator, tell the difference between `|0A 4D 5E 43|` and `|adfsdasd|`? Especially if they are not always alternating? This looks like balanced groups, which, I believe, are only possible via regex in .NET.

Comment: By going through the string from the left side?

Comment: How can you distinguish between the word "ad" and the hex for 173?

Comment: If ad is not enclosed in pipes, then it will be treated as characters.

Comment: For example, start reading line from the left.
When a pipe is seen, convert all words till next pipe to hex.
Then, treat future characters as ascii till pipe is seen.

Comment: You've completely changed the question, making current answers appear to be totally wrong. Please stick to updating your question, rather than changing it.

Comment: Is every other string a hex string, or isn't it? Is every string _entirely_ in the form `(hex-hex-space)*` a hex string, or isn't it? You can answer "yes" to both questions, it makes it easier.

Comment: But you said in response to Alex's question that the pieces weren't alternating.  Otherwise, how would you parse `ad|ad|ad|ad|ad`?  Which ones are hex and which ones aren't, and why?  You can certainly come up with a rule to decide, but either your data is already encoded using that rule or it isn't.

Comment: I'm guessing that `ad` is not hex if found in `|ad nauseum|`, but it's hex in `|ad 4d|`. Nothing else makes much sense in this context. (And perhaps it must be uppercase as well)

Comment: @alexis - I believe it would be something like `a1|a2||a3|a4|a5|a6|a7||a8|a9` where a2, a3, a5, a7 and a8 are hex, the rest are not.

Comment: @jck, you've got backslash escapes now? Anything else you forgot to mention?

Comment: I didn't really intend to have backslash escapes with regex. But since I decided to use python directly, I added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what this might look like in pyparsing:

```
from pyparsing import Word,hexnums,Suppress,OneOrMore

twoDigitHex = Word(hexnums,exact=2)
VERT = Suppress('|')

pattern = VERT + OneOrMore(twoDigitHex) + VERT

# attach parse action to prefix each 2-digit hex with 'x' and join all together
pattern.setParseAction(lambda t: ''.join('x'+tt for tt in t))

# take sample code, and use transformString to apply conversion
sample = "blahblah|0A 4D 5E 43|adfsdasd|92| sgagrewas|12 5E|"
print pattern.transformString(sample)
```

prints

```
blahblahx0Ax4Dx5Ex43adfsdasdx92 sgagrewasx12x5E
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you *could* do it using only a regex, but why bother? It's simple to use your programming language:

Break your string at the vertical bars. Check and substitute if appropriate. Recombine.

```
line = 'blahblah|0A 4D 5E 43|adfsdasd|92| sgagrewas|12 5E|'
parts = line.split('|')
for i, s in enumerate(parts):
    if re.match(r'^([\dA-F]{2} )*[\dA-F]$', s):
    parts[i] = re.sub('^| ', 'x', s)
result = "".join(parts)
```

The check is whether the *entire* substring consists of two-digit hex numbers separated by spaces. I assume all hex letters are capitalized, as in your example.

Comment: I believe that only the odd items would be parsed. Even items would be left alone. Still, +1 for this approach... I think it's easier to read and maintain then a regex solution.

Comment: Well, if the OP will make up his mind, it's easy enough to substitute in the odd array indices only.

Answer (score 0):

I proceeded in 2 times:

- 1st replace every hex value
- then remove blanks and `|`

It gives:

```
>>> s = 'blahblah|0A 4D 5E 43|adfsdasd|92| sgagrewas|12 5E|'
>>> re.sub(r'[| ]', r'', re.sub(r' ?([0-9A-F]{2})', r'x\1', s))
'blahblahx0Ax4Dx5Ex43adfsdasdx92sgagrewasx12x5E'
```

Comment: But there could be values in the string which look like hex.(The string is alphanumeric)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think python is capable of balanced regex expressions. To my knowledge, .NET is the only flavor with such support (and it looks quite ugly and is nightmarish to maintain).

You may be better off splitting the string on the pipe symbol, then rejoining the string, applying the desired formatting (via regex, if so desired) on the odd numbered string array items.

**EDIT:** On second thought, I believe this would be possible using a lookbehind with a variable-length expression, but unfortunately python does not have support for those. (For example, something along the lines of `(?<=^(?:[^|]*\|[^|]*\|)*[^|]*)\|(\w+ ?)*\|`)

Comment: I'm still not sure why you think balancing is needed. The units don't nest, they alternate. It's easy to write an RE for `|hex|<regular text>`, where `<regular text>` is just `[^|]+`